# Solidity VM memory management

Tags: solidity, memory, assembly

I'm trying to do an external function call in assembly.
So I have to prepare a memory area that store the input args.

But where's the address that I should start with mstore?

I mean, there are some solidity code before my assembly {...} part, is there any pointer that always points to the current end of used memory?